# Why does player sometimes move in wrong direction when switching direction

Tags: c, game-engine

I am writing a game-engine in C with SDL2, and am trying to use bit twiddling to store my current moving direction.
I'm not exactly sure of how to reproduce it, but here is a video showing the error:
https://youtu.be/RnPZaUDPElU

And here is the problematic code:

```
#define BMXSPEED 0x01
#define BMYSPEED 0x04

void BEvent (btree_t *t) {
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            t->run = 0;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (event.key.keysym.scancode) {
            case SDL_SCANCODE_ESCAPE:
                t->run = 0;
                break;
            case SDL_SCANCODE_D:
                if (!event.key.repeat) {
                    t->player->speed |= BMXSPEED;
                }
                break;
            case SDL_SCANCODE_A:
                if (!event.key.repeat) {
                    t->player->speed |= (BMXSPEED << 1);
                }
                break;
            case SDL_SCANCODE_S:
                if (!event.key.repeat) {
                    t->player->speed |= BMYSPEED;
                }
                break;
            case SDL_SCANCODE_W:
                if (!event.key.repeat) {
                    t->player->speed |= (BMYSPEED << 1);
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        case SDL_KEYUP:
            switch (event.key.keysym.scancode) {
            case SDL_SCANCODE_D:
                t->player->speed &= ~BMXSPEED;
                break;
            case SDL_SCANCODE_A:
                t->player->speed &= ~(BMXSPEED << 1);
                break;
            case SDL_SCANCODE_S:
                t->player->speed &= ~BMYSPEED;
                break;
            case SDL_SCANCODE_W:
                t->player->speed &= ~(BMYSPEED << 1);
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    /* X movement */
    if (t->player->speed & BMXSPEED && (t->player->speed & (BMXSPEED << 1)) != (BMXSPEED << 1))
        t->player->xspeed += (t->player->xspeedMax - abs(t->player->xspeed)) / t->player->xspeedMax;
    else
    if (t->player->speed & (BMXSPEED << 1) && (t->player->speed & BMXSPEED) != BMXSPEED)
        t->player->xspeed -= (t->player->xspeedMax - abs(t->player->xspeed)) / t->player->xspeedMax;
    else
        t->player->xspeed += (t->player->xspeedMin - t->player->xspeed) / t->player->xspeedMax;

    /* Y movement */
    if (t->player->speed & BMYSPEED && (t->player->speed & (BMYSPEED << 1)) != (BMYSPEED << 1))
        t->player->yspeed += (t->player->yspeedMax - abs(t->player->yspeed)) / t->player->yspeedMax;
    else
    if (t->player->speed & (BMYSPEED << 1) && (t->player->speed & BMYSPEED) != BMYSPEED)
        t->player->yspeed -= (t->player->yspeedMax - abs(t->player->yspeed)) / t->player->yspeedMax;
    else
        t->player->yspeed += (t->player->yspeedMin - t->player->yspeed) / t->player->yspeedMax;

    t->player->rect.x += (int)t->player->xspeed;
    t->player->rect.y += (int)t->player->yspeed;
}
```

EDIT: After changing the method of storing direction, I determined that the problem is not related to bit twiddling.  I suspect it to be the acceleration method.

Comment: what about using a debugger??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your acceleration method is a bit obscure (pun intended), here are 2 suggestions:

- The bit test can be simplified into a single test, masking the player `speed` with 2 bits and checking for a single bit.
- The deceleration case should probably use the `abs` function as well, with an adjustment for the deceleration case.
- The `fabs()` function seems more apropriate than `abs()` if the `xspeed` and `yspeed` members are floating point values.
- Using an intermediary pointer for the player improves readability:

Here is the resulting code:

```
    Player *p = t->player;

    /* X movement */
    if (p->speed & (BMXSPEED * 3) == BMXSPEED)
        p->xspeed += (p->xspeedMax - fabs(p->xspeed)) / p->xspeedMax;
    else
    if (p->speed & (BMXSPEED * 3) == BMXSPEED << 1)
        p->xspeed -= (p->xspeedMax - fabs(p->xspeed)) / p->xspeedMax;
    else
        p->xspeed -= copysign((p->xspeedMin - fabs(p->xspeed)) / p->xspeedMax, p->xspeed);

    /* Y movement */
    if (p->speed & (BMYSPEED * 3) == BMYSPEED)
        p->yspeed += (p->yspeedMax - fabs(p->yspeed)) / p->yspeedMax;
    else
    if (p->speed & (BMYSPEED * 3) == BMYSPEED << 1)
        p->yspeed -= (p->yspeedMax - fabs(p->yspeed)) / p->yspeedMax;
    else
        p->yspeed -= copysign((p->yspeedMin - fabs(p->yspeed)) / p->yspeedMax, p->yspeed);
```

Comment: The only mistake is using `fabs()` in the deceleration method, it will send the player flying to the left.

Comment: @Jameds: you probably want to decrease the absolute value of `xspeed`  and `yspeed` when no key is pressed, although this behavior is questionable. I guess you are moving on a flat surface with non zero friction.  Removing the `fabs()` gives a asymmetric behavior too.  I updated the answer with an alternative.